# javax.servlet.ServletException at Jboss 7.1 Seam 2.2.1 JSF 1.2 project environment

Tags: jsf, maven, richfaces, jboss7.x, seam2

We've developed a web application using Jboss 7.1 + Seam 2.2.1.Final + JSF 1.2 + Richfaces 3.3.3.Final and JBoss Maven Integration 1.0 . We've deployed the our .war file to the application server successfully. But one of the .xhtml page we want to a redirect operation after an action has completed. But browser throws the following exception. We've debug the codes and it seems the exception has been occured at the response phase of the seam. Also there isnot any cause of this exception so we could not the main reason of the exception. Is there anyone has an idea??

```
ERROR [org.jboss.seam.exception.Exceptions] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) handled and logged exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:346) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83) [jboss-seam-2.2.1.Final.jar:2.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40) [jboss-seam-2.2.1.Final.jar:2.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.2.1.Final.jar:2.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90) [jboss-seam-2.2.1.Final.jar:2.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.2.1.Final.jar:2.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64) [jboss-seam-2.2.1.Final.jar:2.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.2.1.Final.jar:2.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45) [jboss-seam-2.2.1.Final.jar:2.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.2.1.Final.jar:2.2.1.Final]
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206) [richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar:3.3.3.Final]
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290) [richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar:3.3.3.Final]
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388) [richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar:3.3.3.Final]
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515) [richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar:3.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56) [jboss-seam-2.2.1.Final.jar:2.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.2.1.Final.jar:2.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60) [jboss-seam-2.2.1.Final.jar:2.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.2.1.Final.jar:2.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158) [jboss-seam-2.2.1.Final.jar:2.2.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:397) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:154) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
```

Comment: Please provide the page code and the Java action code to provide a better analysis of the problem, with that stacktrace is almost impossible to give you a hand.

Comment: I solved the problem using this link http://lucasterdev.altervista.org/wordpress/2011/06/14/working-with-seam-2-2-and-jboss-as-6/.

Comment: In the future questions you should include the *complete* stacktrace. The one which you pasted is just telling that "an exception" has been thrown, but yet you didn't include *that* exception at all. The real exception would in turn have provided clues to the problem.

Comment: @BalusC, There is not any stack trace anyone else.I researched all logs ,but only clue about this the upstairs error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using this link http://lucasterdev.altervista.org/wordpress/2011/06/14/working-with-seam-2-2-and-jboss-as-6/

For the record: in the `pom.xml` of your web project,  exclude the `servlet-api` and `jboss-seam-jul` artifacts from the `jboss-seam-ui` dependency, as shown in the following code snippet:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-seam-ui</artifactId>
    <version>${seam.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-seam-jul</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```